# All maximal subgroups of $M$ are abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $M$ be the modular group of order 16, and consider the following representation: $\langle u,v:u^2=v^8=1,vu=uv^5\rangle$.

How do I show that every maximal subgroup is abelian? I reaaly need to draw the lattice or there is a clever way to prove it? I'm not able to see it.

Comment: An issue of proper MathJax usage arises:
$$
\begin{align}
\textbf{right: } & \langle u,v:u^2=v^8=1,vu=uv^5\rangle \\
\textbf{wrong: } & < u,v:u^2=v^8=1,vu=uv^5>
\end{align}
$$
(I edited accordingly. If you google "latex symbols" you find things like this.) $\qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take two elements $a,b$ that do not commute (which specifically means that one is of the form $v^n$ or $uv^n$ and the other is of the form $uv^m$ with some restrictions on $n,m$ to ensure non-commutativity) and show that $\langle a,b\rangle=M$, which is easiest done by showing that $u,v\in \langle a,b\rangle$.